# Meaning of the word "for" in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Here is the context:

> **For**, doubtless, being ignored or rejected by someone you’re enamored of is associated with all kinds of distress.

Could you please rephrase the sentence for me. I cannot get becouse I cannot understand what *for* was used there for.

Comment: It looks to me like it might be a shortened version of "therefore". As Wordnik says: **for** (*conj.*) Since; because; introducing a reason of something before advanced, a cause, motive, explanation, justification, or the like, of an action related or a statement made; it is logically nearly equivalent to _since_, or _because_, but connects less closely, and is sometimes used as a very general introduction to something suggested by what has gone before. That said, I can't say any more, for you haven't provided the full context (in other words, I can't read the preceding sentence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose this would make more sense with a little context, for instance, the previous sentence. But even without it, **for** might mean, roughly, "because" -- as in

> /.../ Aye, there's the rub,
>   For in that sleep of death, what dreams may come 
>   /.../

So I'd suppose that before your sentence, the talk was about someone reacting in an unusual way after having been rejected, or feeling like killing themselves. Or it may have been about the need to show some patience or consideration with a person who has been rejected. So it could be paraphrased as ...

> Because there is no doubt that being ignored or rejected by someone you’re enamored of is associated with all kinds of distress.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the confusion here is actually coming from the word 'doubtless'. The meaning of the 'for' may be clearer if we remove it

> "For being ignored or rejected ... "

which in this case has similarly meaning as

> "As being ignored or rejected by someone..."

The use of commas in this case acts almost like parentheses so you could read the sentence as

> For (it is doubtless that) being ignored or rejected...

A construction like this usually comes as an elaboration of the previous sentence. For example:

> I hope my parking ticket hasn't expired yet. For it would be a pain to deal with another fine.

Hope this helps.